Azure - GCP identity federation for service principals - where to get access token from?
I'm trying to set up identity federation between GCP and Azure. According to GCP documentation I need to create a managed identity and VM which is kind of a surprise for me. And that example also uses IMDS which is not accessible outside of azure.
I'd like to be able to get that access-token not only from VMs or other resources that have managed identities. Is there an endpoint accessible from outside of Azure and doesn't require managed identity? I'd like to just be able to do similar thing but not necessarily when being in Azure.
curl "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?resource=APP_ID_URI&api-version=2018-02-01" -H "Metadata: true" | jq -r .access_token
I haven't yet found a way to do that, but generally I'd like something similar as what is possible with az cli:
az account get-access-token --resource https://management.azure.com/ -o json

Which azure resource do you use

You cannot. Managed Identity is assigned to the service instance. While running on the instance you can request an authorization token but you cannot outside the instance. Workload Identity Federation is used to exchange one Identity Provider token for another (Azure -> Google). Have you considered using a Google service account instead?

I'd like to have service principal "connected" with service account on GCP side. That means that I'd like to be able to invoke GCP with service principal's token which will be trusted by GCP.

Your question is using a Managed Identity which is a type of service principal but only available inside an Azure service. The Azure metadata server located at 169.254.169.254 is not accessible outside the machine.
